# Clojure JavaFX, ChoiceDialog from another Thread

Tags: multithreading, javafx, clojure

i have an JavaFX based input view. From this view a build up another view with JUNG/jungerer (a graph framework).
No i want to realize, that a ChoiceDialog appears, when a user clicks on a vertex in this graph.

I know how to build up the ChoiceDialog and how to get the result of the choice.

The only problem is, when i click on a vertex in the graph and call the function to build up the ChoiceDialog following Exception is throwed:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = AWT-EventQueue-0
```

I tried it with

```
(javafx.application.Platform/runLater f)
```

f is a function that is called with "runLater".

Does anybody know a solution for this very stupid problem?
I think the problem is, that the graph ui is in a own JFrame..i tried to initialize the jframe in the thread where the input view is running..but that didn't work to..

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is to wrap the FX code in `Platform.runLater(...)`... what was the problem with that approach?

Comment: It was a long day...one line too much..now it works. Thanks!